# В файл записываются последовательности с клавиатуры

Tags: c, память

Не нужен код, нужна светлая идея!!!Вся проблема задачи в эффективном использовании памяти...

1. Последовательности задаются любой длины.
2. Последовательности при вводе отделяются друг от друга специальным символом например: (1 2 4 * 5 94 7).
3. Последовательности записываются в файл, если накопилось 10 чисел - последовательность продолжает записываться на новой строке.
4. Встретился разделитель - конец последовательности, тоже новая строка.

Самая загвоздка

5. Последовательность записывается не в исходном виде, а в измененном. Если в ней присутствуют простые числа, отсортировать по возрастанию и записать их в начало.

Не могу придумать эффективное решение...Длины мы не знаем, создать массив на 10000 чисел не вариант. Мой вариант решения это создать еще один бинарный файл, в который записывается последовательность, потом из этого файла выгружаются простые числа, мы сортируем и записываем их в исходник, а дальше перепись остальных чисел, но оно ведь ужасное... Неужели нет более красивого решения?

Comment: Вы можете накапливать числа в памяти. Растущий массив, список элементов, список групп элементов - вариантов море.

Comment: в файлике миллион чисел, представьте что каждое переполнение происходит realloc, а на следующей последовательности сброс обратно, потом еще второй массив для сортировки? По-моему такое решение еще хуже... Вся суть тут в минимальных затратах памяти и эффективности, задача то элементарная

Comment: Миллион чисел - четыре мегабайта. 20 (прописью - двадцать) реаллокаций. Накладные расходы на реаллокации - три раза по памяти, два раза по времени. У вас нет 12 мегабайт? У вас нет одной миллисекунды?

Comment: Можно работать и просто на диске. В конце концов, во времена DOS с 640К памяти его `sort` сортировал файлы в мегабайты... :) Надо просто выбрать, чем жертвовать - памятью или скоростью.

Comment: 'каждое переполнение происходит realloc, а на следующей последовательности сброс обратно' - а зачем сбрасывать обратно? Пусть остается буфер такого размера, как есть. П.3 конфликтует с п.5 - если п.3 - обязательное требование, то тогда сортировка простых чисел возможно только в одной строке. А если п.5 относится ко всей последовательности, то тогда п.3 должен звучать как "записать последовательность в файл построчно, не более 10 чисел в строке".

Comment: Формулируйте конкретную задачу, подумаем над конкретной реализацией.

Answer (score 2):

Светлая идея состоит в том чтобы попробовать какую-то реализацию. Если она подходит по производительности, идти дальше решать задачу, не рассуждая "о способах заточки мечей".

Миллион целых чисел генерируется и считывается за одну десятую секунды. Девять десятых времени уходит на работу `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int *data;
} array_t;


void reserve(array_t *array, size_t capacity) {
    if (capacity > array->capacity) {
        int *data = realloc(array->data, capacity * sizeof(array->data[0]));
        if (data == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "memory error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        array->capacity = capacity;
        array->data = data;
    }
}

void append(array_t *array, int n) {
    if (array->size == array->capacity) {
        reserve(array, (array->capacity == 0) + 2 * array->capacity);
    }
    array->data[array->size] = n;
    ++array->size;
}

int main() {
    array_t array = {0};
    int n;
    while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        append(&array, n);
    }
    printf("%zu ints were read", array.size);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion read.c 
>
> $ time seq 1000000 | ./a.out
> 1000000 ints were read
> real  0m0.099s
> user  0m0.108s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Если поменять `main` можно измерить накладные расходы заполнение массива неизвестной длины. Одна сотая секунды. При том что выключены любые оптимизации:

```
int main() {
    array_t array = {0};
    for (int n = 0; n < 1000000; ++n) {
        append(&array, n);
    }
    printf("%zu ints were appended", array.size);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion append.c 
>
> $ time ./a.out
> 1000000 ints were appended
> real  0m0.008s
> user  0m0.004s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```